# fitting a number within two bounds

Tags: vba, math, random, range, modulus

I'm working on a program that generates pseudorandom numbers for a user based on their inputted seed, start and end range. I've written my own modulus based generator based on [Lehmer's random number generator algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator). YES I KNOW modulus based random calculations are biased, but for it's use this method is more than adequate.

Anyway, whilst I can generate a string of random numbers from the given seed in VBA, I can't find anything online with a formula or code showing how that number can be scaled down to fit within the supplied upper and lower bound. I'm hoping someone here knows a formula for this, or knows of a website I've missed that covers this sort of process (I don't even know what it would be called - scaling?)

Thanks for your time! In case it's useful or anyone's interested, here's my VBA code generating the seed-based number:

```
random = ((CDec(1664525) * t1) * seed + 1013904223) 't1 is the incremental count for each requested number
random = random - (Int(random / 2 ^ 23) * 2 ^ 21)
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Just to point out, the 'scaling' cannot use the rand function, which I've seen done before, since the final numbers need to be the same each time that seed is used!

Comment: Is the range of the random nuber generator known? Is it all values of some data type?

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "interpolation".

Comment: The range covers any integer between 0 and 999999, negative numbers or decimals will never be requested. so a Long data type variable is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kevin is right I just need to add:

Linear interpolation for range change

- so if you have number `x` on interval `<x0,x1>`
- and want to change it to `y` on interval `<y0,y1>`
- then use this formula:
- `y=y0+((x-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0));`
- it is the formula for 2D line and also base for DDA algorithms ...

What if your x range is unknown ?

- then simply bound it to something known
- for example `x&65535` will change the x range to <0,65535>
- of coarse only if the original x range was higher then that ...

What if dynamic x range is smaller then dynamic y range ?

- ie `|x1-x0|<|y1-y0|`
- the equation still works but you will be missing certain numbers in y range
- so the interval will have gaps
- to avoid that you have to increase effective range of x
- for example like this `x=(rand()&255)|((rand()&255)<<8)`
- so you will use more random numbers per each call
- do not worry the seed stuff will be still working ...

Comment: This looks pretty promising, thank you! Users will not want negative integers from this generator - Long values from 0 to 999999 can be queried.

Sorry, I'm new to reading mathematical notation, what is meant by y0? Is y being multiplied by 0 where 0 is the lower bound?

Comment: @intSparks x0 is min(x) x1 is max(x) y0 is min(y) y1 is max(y) so in your case for non negative values both x0 and y0 are equal to zero, x1 is max output value from your pseudorandom generator and y1 is the desired range

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! Only problem now is I don't know what the upperbound of my modulus randomiser is...

Comment: @intSparks I do not see any modulo in your code (upper bound is the modulo-1 usually) anyways you can measure your bounds ... just take at least 1000000 random numbers and find the min and max values from them ...

Comment: Excel VBA can't handle large numbers in it's MOD operation, so I manually calculate the modulus on line 1 of the code I supplied using arithmetic. That let's VBA consider the output a Long variable type that can hold the calculation result without problems!

Anyway, thank you for the help! I have chosen your answer as the solution to the problem!